# Python error when using Django and Djongo on fresh computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djongo

I recently reformatted my computer and had to setup my enviornment. I pip installed `django`, `djongo`, and then installed MongoDB with Compass.

I pulled my code from Github and tried to run it. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\djongo\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cursor import Cursor
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .sql2mongo.query import Query
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sqlparse import parse as sqlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlparse'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Cody\projects\parser\TestlioParser\adobeparser\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Property(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 141, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 235, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 208, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

My current `pip list`

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.5.0
Django     4.0.4
djongo     1.3.6
pip        22.0.4
pymongo    4.1.1
pytz       2022.1
setuptools 58.1.0
sqlparse   0.2.4
tzdata     2022.1
```

I have tried removing everything and reinstalling it all and that did not change anything. I am unsure how to fix this issue.

Database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'dd',
    }
}
```

Comment: share the `DATABASES` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this pip pointed at C:\Python310?

It's possible that you've installed those packages against a different version of Python or different virtual env.

The django server execution is running in the Python3.10 context, and may not be aware of the packages you've installed in *this specific pip.*

---

Is your real issue is a misconfiguration of the ENGINE setting?

Look at the last few lines of your stacktrace. Django is complaining that you've picked an invalid option for the db['ENGINE'] setting.

```
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 208, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(  
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: Yes pip is pointed to C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip. I only have Python 310 on this computer.

Comment: I reinstalled Python. I see that ```C:\Program Files\Python310``` is where it put it this time. I have the path ```C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages``` and then I also have ```C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages``` and this has all my packages in it like Django, Djongo, etc.

Comment: @xf900 so installing again Python solved the problem? I'm facing the same issue